# How to get the actual kernel value of the Mat returned from OpenCV getGaussianKernel?

Tags: c++, opencv, gaussian, mat

I am currently trying to implement a custom size M*N Gaussian Blur on an image using CUDA.

I intend to use OpenCV getGuassianKernel to get a M*1 kernel and perform a CUDA vertical gaussian blur operation, then get another 1*N kernel and perform another CUDA horizontal gaussian blur operation.

How can I retrieve the actual float value in the kernel? I just tried the following way and the behaviour seems weird:

```
Mat kernel= getGaussianKernel(3, -1);

cout << kernel<< endl;   //yields[0.25,5,0.25]

vector<float> kernel_vector;
for (int i = 0; i < kernel.rows; ++i) {
    kernel_vector.insert(kernel_vector.end(), kernel.ptr<float>(i), kernel.ptr<float>(i)+kernel.cols);
}
for(auto i : kernel_vector){
    cout << i << endl;   //yields[0,0,0]
}
```

Comment: kernel.ptr<double>(i)

Comment: @Miki oh!didn't know it returns a double Mat, thanks alot I've been stucked for days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `cv::getGaussianKernel` returns a `Mat` of type `CV_64FC1`, so you need to access it like:

```
kernel.at<double>(i,j);
```

For clarity, I usually use `Mat_<T>`:

```
Mat1d kernel = getGaussianKernel(...);
```

And access it like:

```
kernel(i,j);
```